# Use of if in shells

Tags: shell

I need to compare values present in 2 different arrays. I have tried writing a code. But it is not working properly. I am very new to shell scripting. Please help !
CODE ::

```
declare -a ARR1
declare -a ARR2
val1=`cat input1.txt`
val2=`cat input2.txt`
ARR1=( $val1 )
ARR2=( $val2 )
num1=`wc -w input1.txt | sed 's/input1.txt//g'`
num2=`wc -w input2.txt | sed 's/input2.txt//g'`
for ((i=0;i<$num1;i++))
do
    for ((j=0;j<$num2;j++))
    do 
        if ["${ARR1[i]}" == "${ARR2[j]}"];then
            echo "EQUAL"
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

The inputs will be two files input1 and input2.

**Content of input1**

```
   /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml
   /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/Utils/svcPublishWMOS_CTL/flow.xml
   /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/Utils/svcMapIDPDataForPRandCA/flow.xml
```

**Content of input2**

```
   /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcReprocessASNManifest/flow.xml
   /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml
   /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/Utils/svcPublishWMOS_CTL/flow.xml
   /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/Utils/svcMapIDPDataForPRandCA/flow.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
if ["${ARR1[i]}" == "${ARR2[j]}"];then
```

misses required spaces. It should be:

```
if [ "${ARR1[i]}" == "${ARR2[j]}" ];then
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to compare 2 arrays you can do:

```
[[ $(printf "%s" "${array1[@]}") == $(printf "%s" "${array2[@]}") ]]
```